# Contacts are duplicated in People application

Tags: windows-8, contacts, windows-8-people-app

I'm facing a problem due to the People application in Windows 8 make my contacts duplicated, but I can't delete them anyway, it just allow me to edit. Please take a look at my image below:
[image]

This is what exactly I do last night:

1. Login to the web mail outlook.com (I use live account), then go to People
2. Choose Google account to connect

Then I went to Windows 8 People application, I found my contacts duplicated (2 people for each contact). I tried to link them with the other, but it does not allow me to do that. Thus, I remove the connection between Live and Google, nothing changes.

Feeling sad but tried to reconnect again, not luckier, but my contacts were more duplicated (3 people for each contact instead of 2 people as before)

I guessed that something were cached so I restart the Windows, I really shocked when found my contacts now were 4 people for each contact. It's so bad.

Can any body help me about this, please?

Comment: I would delete all your contacts through the People application then download your contacts again.

Comment: That's not a good idea, but I will try. How can I delete them?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

[People app showing empty contacts, can't delete?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-security/people-app-showing-empty-contacts-cant-delete/4c70c549-00c2-46c4-a250-3251b7918918)

**Vijay B replied on  November 20, 2012**

***Support Engineer  Community Star***

> Hi Khaotik,
>
> Thank you for posting in Microsoft Windows Community. I understand
>   that you are unable to delete duplicate contacts in the People App. 
>   Do you have multiple accounts configured that have the same contacts?
>
> - Method 1 If you only have the Microsoft account, then try deleting the duplicates by following the steps in the below link:
>     http://contacts.live.com
> - Method 2 I would suggest you to uninstall and re-install people App and see if that helps. a. Right click on People App b. In the bottom
>     tray click on Uninstall. c. Now hover the mouse pointer to the upper
>     right corner and click on “Search” d. Select “Store” and in the search
>     bar type People, now try installing the People app. Hope this
>     information is helpful and do let us know if you need further
>     assistance. We will be glad to assist.

Comment: Thank you! Method 1 does not work for me, method 2 is fine. But when I re-install People app, it lost all of linking. Now, it does not allow me to link People again

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 *should* be doing a better job of automatically linking these contacts.

I wonder whether it is struggling with the character set. I also notice from your screenshot that you are linked with Facebook, Skype and Twitter as well as Outlook.com which would explain why you are ending up with 4 dupes.

However, you could try linking contacts automatically. Click through to a contact and right click to bring up the bar at the bottom of the screen and then select 'link'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The screenshot above is result of Live and Google only, I've turned other account off from displaying. In case I select no linked account. The screenshot will be 3 people per contact.
I cannot link and delete them anyway.